# Normalizing survey database

Tags: sql, join, normalize

So I'm trying to normalize my database and having trouble figuring out how to do it (I'm very new to all of this).

I have 5 tables being played with. First one has all my data and was my original super table. The other 4 are the new normalized versions. Please note that the Joe Blow entry is simply an example, in reality I have thousands of entries on all of these except for the answers table (the one I'm trying to populate with thousands of new entries):

> ### Table: questions (original non normalized table)
>
> unique_ID (PK) | answer | question | pName
>
> 2000 |Yes | Are you Happy with Life? | Joe Blow
>
> ---

my new table is identical really, except this time i'm using all keys:

> ### Table: answers
>
> unique_ID (PK) | answer_ID (FK) | question_ID (FK) |  person_ID (FK)
>
> ---

so this said, I'm trying to figure out how to use an insert into statement to make this work. The other tables match the ID's with the data and they are currently populated:

> ### Table: answers_only
>
> answer_ID (FK) | answer
>
> 3555 | Yes
>
> ---
>
> ### Table: questions_only
>
> question_Id (FK) | question
>
> 4231 | Are you Happy with Life?
>
> ---
>
> ### Table: user
>
> person_ID (PK,FK) | pName
>
> 2212 | Joe Blow
>
> ---
>
> so basically the first part is something like:
>   INSERT INTO answers(person_ID, answer_ID, question_ID) VALUES(person_ID, answer_ID, questionID)

I just don't know how to get those values

Answer (score 0):

Based on the way you've described your schema `Table: Questions` is actually in `3NF`. 
`1NF` -> Table is flat (i.e. there are not two answers in one answer column)
`2NF` -> Table columns are all `functionally dependent` on the primary key as a whole (i.e. answer,question, person are all dependent on unique_id)
`3NF` -> Table columns are not `functionally dependent` on non candidate keys.

`Note:` I would remove the `unique_id` key from `answers` table it seems redundant.

For inserting you could use a subquery for each column

```
INSERT INTO answers(person_ID,answer_ID,question_ID)
SELECT (SELECT person_ID FROM user WHERE pName = 'Joe Blow'),(SELECT answer_ID FROM answers_only WHERE answer = 'Yes'), (SELECT question_ID FROM questions_only WHERE question = 'Are you Happy with Life?')
```

Comment: The Joe Blow entry was just an example. I need to do a mass data transfer with thousands of names.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at two approaches.  The first one would have these tables:

```
person - PersonId, name, etc
Survey - SurveyId, name, etc
Question - QuestionId, text, etc
Answer - AnswerId, text, etc

SurveyQuestion - SurveyId, QuestionId, etc
SurveyAnswer - SurveyId, QuestionId, PersonId, AnswerId, etc
```

The second one would not have an answer table and the SurveyAnswer table would have a varchar field for the answer instead of an AnswerId field.

Regarding the etc in the Question, Answer, SurveyQuestion, and SurveyAnswer tables, I like to timestamp all my records.  However, that's just me.